# Exposing cmd.exe from zsh

Tags: cmd, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

On windows subsystem for linux, I can acces the native windows comand prompt through

```
$ cmd.exe [command]
```

However, when running oh-my-zsh, The cmd.exe api does not seem to be exposed...

```
$ cmd.exe
zsh: command not found: cmd.exe
```

How can I expose the `cmd.exe` api to be available in oh-my-zsh?

Comment: What is the value of the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Just had to set my `PATH` variable in zsh equal to the one in WSL (no zsh)...